# C# Application is in break mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, bartender

I'm struggling to get my application out of break mode, here is what happened:

This was my code and everything worked ok:

```
Engine btEngine = new Engine();
btEngine.Start();
LabelFormatDocument SerialPlate = btEngine.Documents.Open(@"C:\Afrisoft\Labels\ItemLabel_General.btw");
LabelFormatDocument BoxLabel = btEngine.Documents.Open(@"C:\Afrisoft\Labels\BoxLabel_General.btw");
SerialPlate.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["JobNumber"].Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
BoxLabel.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["JobNumber"].Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
Result SerialPlateResult = SerialPlate.Print();
Result BoxLabelResult = BoxLabel.Print();
btEngine.Stop();
```

Then I changed it to the following as the documentation suggested:

```
using (Engine btEngine = new Engine(true))
{
    LabelFormatDocument SerialPlate = btEngine.Documents.Open(@"C:\Afrisoft\Labels\ItemLabel_General.btw");
    LabelFormatDocument BoxLabel = btEngine.Documents.Open(@"C:\Afrisoft\Labels\BoxLabel_General.btw");
    SerialPlate.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["JobNumber"].Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    BoxLabel.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["JobNumber"].Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    Result SerialPlateResult = SerialPlate.Print();
    Result BoxLabelResult = BoxLabel.Print();
```

I inserted a break point at:

```
using (Engine btEngine = new Engine(true))
```

and then when I took the break point away to test that part as well the app keeps crashing at that point. I've re-added the reference, changed the code back to the when it did work, but nothing fixes it.

Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to update seagull in the nuget pacakge manager

Comment: Are you sure the code is compiled again? Right click on the project in the explorer window and chose "Rebuild Solution".

Comment: Have you tried verifying the existence of OR copying the referenced class libraries to the execution path of your application?

Comment: Looks like a nuget package issue.
Try doing the following:
1) update-package -reinstall under the nuget package manager console
2) delete the obj and bin folders in the target project
3) rebuild project
most importantly - make sure that this nuget package is installed in the entry point project (say - the Console Application project which runs this code)

Comment: The dll comes from bartender's installed folder, when referencing the dll it copies that dll and a xml file to the execution path. I deleted everything in the bin folder and rebuild the project and same thing still happens.

Comment: Is the dll getting copies to the bin folder?

Comment: It looks like the break instruction is stuck somewhere.

Comment: @GalZohar yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the library broke, reinstalling it fixed the issue